# JQuery Sortable, how to allow only once instance of an item?

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using a list of items with an 'Add' button on each to generate a JQuery Sortable list. I'd like to lock the functionality so that certain items can only have one instance on the list, but others can be added multiple times. I tried adding this lock at the list stage using ColdFusion, but I think it would be more effective to edit the JQuery. Here is the code;

```
function presentationAddToAgenda(presentationId) {  

var newAgendaLength = $("#sortable li").length;

    if(presentationId === 1)
    {
    var presentatioName = "Biology";
    }
else if(presentationId === 2)
    {
    var presentatioName = "Microbiology";
    }

   var $li = $('<li id="agendaItem_'+newAgendaLength+'">'+presentatioName+' <select                                                                           
   name="agendaItemTime" id="agendaItemTime"><option>05</option>                         
   <option>10</option><option>15</option></select> <div    
  id="agendaSpeaker"></div> <div id="agendaRemoveItem" onClick="removeAgendaItem(this);">        
   </div></li>');
    $("#sortable").append($li);
    $(function() {         
    $('#sortable li').mousedown(function(){ $(this).addClass('grabbed')});
    $('#sortable li').mouseup(function(){ $(this).removeClass('grabbed')});
     });
$("#sortable").sortable( "refresh" );
$("#sortable").sortable( "refreshPositions" );  
     };
```

Comment: What kind of item do you want only once? And what is ColdFusion?

Comment: ColdFusion is a propriatary web application language. I want each list item only once on the list. Otherwise you could theoretically add infinite amounts of the same item.

Comment: Can you shwo HTML as well please. How do you distinguish betwenn `li` elements?